# Automatically unpin applications every logon

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, automation, pinning

My employer has set up my computer with a script that restores certain pinned programs every logon. Since I use quick launch for my shortcuts, the pinned icons are redundant (and mix with window tiles). I can unpin them with the mouse, but they reappear when I sign out and back in.

I am trying to figure out how I can write a batch script (or similar) to automatically remove the pinned applications, that I can run on startup. I do have local admin access to the computer.

I tried setting the group policy `"Do not allow pinning programs to the Taskbar"`, but the icons still reappear. Deleting the contents of `%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar` has removed the icons of the pinned items, but not removed them.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a delayed login task that will unpin the items.

A reliable little command-line tool that I have found is
[Pin to Taskbar](http://www.technosys.net/products/utils/pintotaskbar).

The command line to unpin a program is:

```
syspin "C:/path/file.exe" c:5387
```

Try the program manually, and if it works then create the login task
for all the icons.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to figure out how I can write a batch script (or similar) to automatically remove the pinned applications, that I can run on startup.

[Batch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) script from [thewindowsclub.com](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/unpin-all-taskbar-icons-at-once-in-windows) to remove all pinned applications:

```
DEL /F /S /Q /A "%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\*"
REG DELETE HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband /F
taskkill /F /IM explorer.exe & start explorer
```

Explanation:

> The first line helps you delete the *TaskBar *folder from the File Explorer. The second line lets you delete the Registry key named *Taskband*, which is visible in the HKCU. The third line lets you restart the File Explorer or Windows Explorer process.

Save it as `.bat` and run it/add as a start-up script:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easy with **PowerShell**:

Remove '*Mail*' icon:

```
((New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace("shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}").Items() | ?{$_.Name -eq "Mail"}).Verbs() | ?{$_.Name.replace("&","") -match "Unpin from taskbar"} | %{$_.DoIt(); $exec = $true}
```

Remove '*Microsoft Store*' icon:

```
((New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace("shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}").Items() | ?{$_.Name -eq "Microsoft Store"}).Verbs() | ?{$_.Name.replace("&","") -match "Unpin from taskbar"} | %{$_.DoIt(); $exec = $true}
```

Note: This was tested on Windows 11.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably another way to do it without a script. In Windows 10 you can configure your taskbar using an XML.

**Here is a sample of the XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LayoutModificationTemplate
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/LayoutModification"
    xmlns:defaultlayout="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/FullDefaultLayout"
    xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout"
    xmlns:taskbar="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/TaskbarLayout"
    Version="1">
  <CustomTaskbarLayoutCollection>
    <defaultlayout:TaskbarLayout>
      <taskbar:TaskbarPinList>
        <taskbar:UWA AppUserModelID="Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge" />
        <taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\System Tools\File Explorer.lnk" />
      </taskbar:TaskbarPinList>
    </defaultlayout:TaskbarLayout>
 </CustomTaskbarLayoutCollection>
</LayoutModificationTemplate>
```

For more details and options check [this Microsoft Doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/configure-windows-10-taskbar).

After creating the XML you can load it with a group policy. To configure Start Layout policy settings in Local Group Policy Editor:

1. Run gpedit
2. Go to User Configuration or Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates >Start Menu and Taskbar and load your XML.

You can get more details at this [Microsoft Doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/customize-windows-10-start-screens-by-using-group-policy).

This should theoretically work but i'm not sure if your XML and policy can actually overwrite theirs.

Comment: I think this is the case too, but I don't think that a local XML can override a GPO xml.